# How to log username in Apache logs?

Tags: apache, security, authentication, iis, apache-log-files

I need some help regarding how to log the user-name into apache logs. I'm building a use-case for Security Information Event Management.

Is the method the same in case of IIS or just applicable to apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the basic authentication user name is placed into apache logs by default.  From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html a typical log configuration is

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog logs/access_log common
```

Where %u is the user name.

I'm not very familiar with iis, but it appears that the basic authentication user name is logged as cs-username.  Here is the documentation http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/676400bc-8969-4aa7-851a-9319490a9bbb.mspx

Comment: Great help:) Stephen